# Unable to locate Container folder in aufs/diff

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

I am unable to find the `Docker Container ID` folder in `aufs/diff` folder:

[image]

If I remove a container or local images (using `rm` / `rmi`) then I can see a few folders getting deleted from the `aufs/diff` folder. How does this mapping take place between `ContainerID / ImageID` and the directory name inside `aufs/diff` folder?

**EDIT: Output of `docker info`**

```
root@ip-172-31-34-158:/home/ubuntu# docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 7
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: overlay host bridge null
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-1022-aws
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 990.9 MiB
Name: ip-172-31-34-158
ID: W6FS:JOLT:B2DT:XN4L:DDN5:5Q3G:RITI:IBSN:SPMC:DIH3:TCPT:IGZO
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: add output of `docker info` to your question

Comment: Why are you looking for the folder? You should not be looking at how docker internally stores stuff. Because it changes based on storage driver and wont be same on different OS. So list your intentions, so a better solution can be suggested

Comment: A few files were created in the container and I need to know the path where the files get stored in host physical disk. Please let me know how to get the host disk path where the files gets stored.

Comment: If you need to know the host path of files created by your container you are probably doing something wrong. If you need to explicitly share files with the host, use a host mount (`-v /host/path:/container/path`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `docker diff` command. Consider the below flow

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu:16.04 bash
root@409b5316d718:/# mkdir -p /find/me/if/you/can
root@409b5316d718:/# touch /etc/newconfig
root@409b5316d718:/# touch /find/me/if/you/can/hereiam
root@409b5316d718:/# exit
```

Then you get the container id of the last exited container

```
$ docker ps -a -q -l
409b5316d718
```

Use docker diff to find what have been changed, added or delete

```
$ docker diff 409b5316d718
C /etc
A /etc/newconfig
A /find
A /find/me
A /find/me/if
A /find/me/if/you
A /find/me/if/you/can
A /find/me/if/you/can/hereiam
C /root
A /root/.bash_history

C = Change
A = Added
D = Deleted
```

**Edit-1**

Now to know the changes on the disk you need to find more info. This again is specific to AUFS driver implementation and won't work on other drivers.

First you need to find the full container id of your container. This can be done using below

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Id }}' 409b5316d718
409b5316d7186f5dfb91d3d016841c7aba2c7aa3cf6e8969beff1a8ea728fa0e
```

Next you need find the ID of the top mount layer, this you can do with below

```
$ ID=409b5316d7186f5dfb91d3d016841c7aba2c7aa3cf6e8969beff1a8ea728fa0e

$ cat /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/mounts/$ID/mount-id
82f629a33f82936f91a61d1edfd4d19ccb5b684b933a10d2bf2c6e54278b7d2f
```

Once you have the mount ID you can list the content of that

```
$ tree  /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/82f629a33f82936f91a61d1edfd4d19ccb5b684b933a10d2bf2c6e54278b7d2f/
/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/82f629a33f82936f91a61d1edfd4d19ccb5b684b933a10d2bf2c6e54278b7d2f/
├── etc
│   └── newconfig
├── find
│   └── me
│       └── if
│           └── you
│               └── can
│                   └── hereiam
└── root

7 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: This will show the files modified inside the docker and is good. But where can I find these files in my hard drive once the container is stopped/detached? It should be somewhere inside the `aufs/diff`, hence just wanted to know how the folders in `aufs/diff` gets mapped with the `Container ID/Image ID`.

Comment: This is really helpful